# Why does the sendmail.mc file support entries that are not formatted for m4 syntax?

Tags: centos, sendmail

I recently discovered that `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` supports entries that are *not* in m4 syntax.  For example:

```
LOCAL_CONFIG
O CipherList=HIGH
```

This doesn't make sense to me because pretty much everything else that is default in the mc file has the expected syntax (e.g. `dnl define(` )

What types of things require m4 syntax in the MC file and what doesn't?

Answer (score 3):

Sendmail ultimately uses a sendmail.cf file. This sort of syntax lets you add lines directly to sendmail.cf without any macro conversion. Back in the olden days, people edited their sendmail.cf files directly and we didn't have sendmail.mc files

If you look at the sendmail.cf file that sendmail.mc generates (via m4), you'll see a lot of:

```
O variable=value
```

lines.

Answer (score 2):

`m4` is a macro processor.

The `sendmail.cf` file which Sendmail actually uses has its own unique format, which has nothing to do with `m4`, and is extremely difficult for people to understand and work with.

Rather, `m4` is used as a preprocessor to *generate* the `sendmail.cf` file from the `sendmail.mc` file. The macros you would use in the `sendmail.mc` are much easier to understand, and hide most of the complexity of the true configuration.

Comment: IMHO m4 would be replaced by another tool with longer future before sendmail.  Current maintainers plan to switch to meta and code fork is unlikely IMHO.